# CKEditor output text do not line breaks automatically

Tags: css, width, ckeditor, line-breaks

the result text of CKEditor does not display correctelly.

The result is something like that:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... and goes outer of the page.

I want it to line break automatically and then the result will be like

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Is this CKEditor configuration or CSS configuration?

Comment: Please provide version of the editor and creator (inline editing or framed editing). It's hard to guess without basic information.

Comment: What is your source ? Can you add a JSFiddle with your problem ?